# reading list from binary file

Tags: c#, list, binaryfiles

the problem i am having is that i can get the file to ready but my read code only seems to read 1 value in a 2 value list.i am stumped as to where this is going wrong. code as follows :

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Windows.Forms;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

 namespace test
 {

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [Serializable]
    public class ore
    {
        public float Cost;

    }



    private List<ore> oreData = new List<ore>();
    private ore b1 = null;
    private ore b2 = null;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        b1 = new ore();
        b2 = new ore();
        oreData.Add(b1);
        oreData.Add(b2);

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 1st text box input is float
        float tempFloat;


        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {
            oreData[0].Cost = tempFloat;
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");



    }


    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 2nd text box input is float
        float tempFloat;
        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {
            oreData[1].Cost = tempFloat;
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");


    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("ore.dat", FileMode.Create);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        bf.Serialize(fs, oreData);
        fs.Close();
    }

    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 3rd text box 
    }

    private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //4th text box
    }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("ore.dat", FileMode.Open);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        oreData = (List<ore>)bf.Deserialize(fs);
        fs.Close();

        if (oreData!=null)
        {
            if (oreData.Count > 0)
                textBox3.Text = oreData[0].Cost.ToString();//update the 3rd text box
            if (oreData.Count > 1)
                textBox4.Text = oreData[1].Cost.ToString();//update the 4th text box

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: i am new to C# and im not sure if these lines are creating a new list when i pass a value to them :  b1 = new ore(); 
         b2 = new ore();

Comment: No. They're just creating the ore objects.  If you want a list that contains those objects you need something like what you did in `button1_Click()`.

Comment: Two things - 1. the lines you mentioned in your comment do not create the list. The line `List<ore> oreData = new List<ore>()` creates the list. 2. The line `List<ore> books = new List<ore>();` isn't doing anything, since it is hidden by the `List<ore> books` inside the `button2_Click` method.

Comment: You might try using a debugger with a breakpoint in `button1_Click` to make sure your list `oreData` contains the data you think it contains prior to serialization.

Comment: okay so number 2 fixed now only: list<ore> books : is there but i still get the value of b1.Titan in both boxes 3 and 4

Comment: @ Michael how do i do that. im sorry if i sound very new but i am very very new

Comment: just figured the break point out .... it was VERY helpful the variable Titan gets its value but the variable Eperton gets a value of 0.0

Comment: now im a bit confused as to why? did i not write the list correctly?

Comment: @doc: You have two `ore` objects (called `b1` and `b2`), each of which has a `Titan` and an `Eperton` member inside of it. This gives a total of four members which need values. In your code, you only give `b1.Titan` and `b2.Eperton` a value. You still need to give `b1.Eperton` and `b2.Titan` a value.

Comment: @ken i changed ore to only have the float Cost updated all b1 and b2 to b1.Cost and b2.Cost. issue of first value in both output boxes remains :(((

Comment: code has been re pasted so changes can be seen

Comment: http://i55.tinypic.com/fyel28.png this shows the debug with a break right before it saves the list to file and both values are the value of text box 1

Comment: If you're going to use the class-level `List`, then it might be a good idea to try removing the `b1` and `b2` variables, replacing them completely with `oreData[0]` and `oreData[1]`.

Comment: question code updated with all new changes

Comment: changed a few things as follows :    private ore oreData = null;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           oreData[0] = new ore();
           oreData[1] = new ore();
            oreData.Add (oreData[0]);
            oreData.Add(oreData[0]);

Comment: the above gets the following error Error 1 Ambiguity between 'test.Form1.oreData' and 'test.Form1.oreData'

Comment: A BIG THANK YOU to both Ken Wayne VanderLinde and Jalal Aldeen Saa'd. you guys are awesome. thank you for helping a newb to learn a few things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found your problem! (Oh my eyes hurt!)

Look at the `if` statement in your `textbox1_changed` and `textbox2_changed` methods. They are both

```
if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
```

But the second one should say

```
if (float.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out tempFloat))
```

Notice that `textbox1` is changed to `textbox2`. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a List and add the b1, b2 items to it, then whenever you serialize or deserialize data, deserialize it to the same list.

Note: it is also a good idea to rename your TextBoxes and Buttons to something more readable like: instead of `textBox2`=> `FirstBookEpertonTextBox`, `textBox2_TextChanged`=> `firstBookEpertonTextBox_TextChanged` or `OnFirstBookEpertonTextBox_TextChanged`, `button1`=> `saveBooksButton`, `Form1`=> `BooksMainForm`....

**Update:** Also consider use the list only instead of b1 and b2 like: books[0] instead of b1 and books[1] instead of b2 and so if the number of books increases the code maintainability will not be a problem. note that you are using a list to serialize and deserialize anyway.

```
[Serializable]
public class ore
{
    public float Cost;
}

private List<ore> books = new List<ore>(); // create a list at class level

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    books.Add(new ore());
    books.Add(new ore());
}


private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // 1st text box input is float
    float tempFloat;
    if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
    {
        books[0].Cost = tempFloat;
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("uh oh");
}


private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // 2nd text box input is float
    float tempFloat;
    if (float.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out tempFloat))
    {
        books[1].Cost = tempFloat;
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("uh oh");
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("ore.dat", FileMode.Create);
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    bf.Serialize(fs, books);
    fs.Close();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("ore.dat", FileMode.Open);
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

    /*use the old list don't create new one 
    and also the new one you are creating has the same
    name as the class level one which may makes conflicts to you.*/
    books = (List<ore>)bf.Deserialize(fs);

    fs.Close();

    if (books!=null)
    {
        if (books.Count > 0)
        {
            //we don't need d1, d2 any more
            //b1 = books[0];
            textBox3.Text = books[0].Cost.ToString();
        }
        if (books.Count > 1)
        {
            //we don't need d1, d2 any more
            //b2 = books[1];
            textBox4.Text = books[1].Cost.ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: -1: He shouldn't have to deserialize to the same variable. After all, a new list is being created, which can be referred to using any `List<ore>` variable. In fact, using the same or different variable should have nothing to do with his problem

Comment: @Ken: When deserializing from a list, the old list he made at the class level will be obsolete. so he should update it and also update the other values at the class like the b1, b2. Note that he at some time may stop using b1, b2 and only use List due to number of books increase or so.

Comment: @Jalal: He doesn't even use the class-level list anywhere in his code - he might as well get rid of it. That list has nothing whatsoever to do with his code. Although your code will work, it does not show the OP what his problem his (in fact, I'm still stumped about it).

Comment: He should use it instead of the b1 and b2.. books[0] instead of b1 books[1] instead of b2 and so on...

Comment: @Jalal i did change my code to what you suggested if for nothing else it looks cleaner and works better. however the issue still remains i enter 2 values and the same value ( the first one i enter ) displays in both output boxes

Comment: @jalal can you show me a example of where i change b1 to books[0] please ?

Comment: @doc: I updated the code. I remove the d1 and d2 and replace them with books[0] and books[1].

Comment: @doc: I didn't see your question code updated, I update the code again.

Comment: @doc: your problem where at the textBox2_TextChanged. your code was `if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))` when you should use `if (float.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out tempFloat))` "textBox2.Text instead of textBox1.Text"  Your problem solved :)

Comment: @jalal you are a saint bud. i have spent so much time figuring this was a code error i never though it was a simple as change a 1 to a 2 OMG

Comment: @doc: note that my answer is still -1!